# How to search data from tableView in ipad and show that data in same table.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, full-text-search

I have text field from which, I want that if user enters any data and it matches to the any of the cell in tableView then it must show.I have used text field for searching the data from table.

This is how, I am populating data in the tableView as below:

```
     - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {

    NSLog(@"Number of Sections");
    if(section == 0)
    return @"Sales";
    if(section == 1)
    return @"Soft Skills";
   }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {


       if (section==0)
    {
    appDelegate = (MultipleDetailViewsWithNavigatorAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    int count=[resultArray count];

    NSLog(@"resultArry Row Counts is %d",count);

    return [resultArray count];
    }

       else{
    appDelegate = (MultipleDetailViewsWithNavigatorAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    int count=[resultArrayOne count];

    NSLog(@"resultArry Row Counts is %d",count);

    return [resultArrayOne count];
      }
         }


        - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath     

      {

     NSLog(@"Table Cell Data");
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

         UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

         if (cell == nil) {
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

       }

   cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;


   if (indexPath.section==0) {


    appDelegate = (MultipleDetailViewsWithNavigatorAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


    ObjectData *theCellData = [resultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *cellValue =theCellData.sub_Category;
    NSLog(@"Cell Values %@",cellValue);
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

    return cell;

       }

      else {

    appDelegate = (MultipleDetailViewsWithNavigatorAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    ObjectData *theCellData = [resultArrayOne objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *cellValue =theCellData.sub_Category;
    NSLog(@"Cell Values %@",cellValue);
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
    return cell;

    }
          }


      -(void)textFieldTextDidChange:(UITextField*)tf{



   NSString*test  = searchTextField.text ;

   }
```

Comment: See the docs for `UISearchDisplayController` and look at Apple's `TableSearch` sample app.

Comment: use a search bar instead of uitextfield

Comment: please Google it my Frnd there are lots of similar exampple Provide by man user of also apple sample code

Comment: http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2009/01/uitableview-searching-table-view.html

Answer (score 0):

try like this may be it helps you,

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@",  txtSearch.text];
    NSArray *ResultArray = [yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    [table reloadData];
    return YES;
}
```

in above code replace Your array.

if you want to show the table data which is having substring of the textfield then use below code.

```
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@",  txtSearch.text];
```

Comment: above method is a delegate method of the textfield ,so you can set delegate to the textfield.

Comment: it is giving error not Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't do a substring operation with something that isn't a string (lhs = <ObjectData: 0x62585d0> rhs = )'

Comment: use this one for search textField.text by using above code it'l work  efficiently..

Comment: again eror Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't use in/contains operator with collection <ObjectData: 0x62c46b0> (not a collection)'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26422/discussion-between-sunny-and-developer-ios)

Answer (score 0):

Search Data from `UITableview` ,You can Use `SearchBar`. you can see in many Denmo projects or example all can use `SearchBar` in Searching Data in `Tableview` . the below code of `SearchBar`.

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{

    searchName = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init] ;
    for(NSString *name in yourArraySeaching)
    {
        NSRange r = [name rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if(r.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            [searchName addObject:name];
            tempSearch=1;
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need one more **temp array** for searching purpose same as **main array**, one array maintaining **searching array's IDs**.

Boolean value for Searching :: `bool searching;`

Code ::

```
-(void)textFieldTextDidChange:(UITextField*)tf {

    int len = [[tf.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] length];

    if (len < [mainArray count]) {

        [tempArray removeAllObjects];
        [tempArrayIds removeAllObjects];

        for(NSString *curString in tempArray)
        {
            NSString *substringRange = [curString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, tf.length)];

            // Converting SearchChar and Firstchar of contestname into lower case

            NSString *searchChar = [tf lowercaseString];
            NSString *FirstChar = [substringRange lowercaseString];

            //NSLog(@"values is %@",substringRange);

            if ([FirstChar isEqualToString:searchChar]) {

                if ([tf isEqualToString:@""]) {

                    searching = false;
                    [tf resignFirstResponder];
                }
                else
                {
                    searching = true;
                    [tempArray addObject:curString];

                    indexVal = [tempArray indexOfObject:curString];

                    NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexVal];
                    [tempArrayIds addObject:s];
                }
           }
       }
       [tblView reloadData];
    }
```

Table Methods ::

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

     if (searching)
        return [tempArray count];
    else
        return [mainArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(searching)
    {
        int k = [[tempArrayIds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue];
        cell.title.text = [mainArray objectAtIndex:k];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.title.text = [mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Hopefully, it'll help you.

Thanks.

Comment: but i have two sections of the table and i have two arrays for two sections

Comment: for that you can replace "mainArray" with any array that you want for searching.

Answer (score 0):

I usually prefer using the freely available Sensible TableView framework to do that. The framework will fetch the data and provide all the searching functionality for you automatically.